# Hide filenames in type command batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv, types

I'm creating a batch file and the final part of the batch is to concatenate the text from multiple csv files into one. The csv that is created is correct, however when I run the command it shows the file names on a separate line. Even with echo off it still shows. When I simply copy and paste the line into a blank txt file and use `@echo off` and that's it.. it still shows the output.

```
type lak-print01.csv lak-print02.csv lak-print03.csv lak-print04.csv or-sdc-print.csv tac-print01.csv tac-print02.csv tuk-print01.csv wa-02print01.csv wa-110print01.csv wa-61print01.csv > MasterPrinterList.csv
```

The output shown in cmd line is as follows. I just want it to perform the type command w/o showing the files.

```
lak-print02.csv



lak-print03.csv



lak-print04.csv



or-sdc-print.csv



tac-print01.csv



tac-print02.csv



tuk-print01.csv



wa-02print01.csv



wa-110print01.csv



wa-61print01.csv
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect StdErr to `nul` by appending `2>nul`.  (`type` outputs filenames into that.)  The command you want is this:

```
type lak-print01.csv lak-print02.csv lak-print03.csv lak-print04.csv or-sdc-print.csv tac-print01.csv tac-print02.csv tuk-print01.csv wa-02print01.csv wa-110print01.csv wa-61print01.csv > MasterPrinterList.csv 2>nul
```

Comment: Thanks!! I appreciate it, that helps and does what I intended

Answer (score 1):

```
type lak-print01.csv lak-print02.csv lak-print03.csv lak-print04.csv or-sdc-print.csv tac-print01.csv tac-print02.csv tuk-print01.csv wa-02print01.csv wa-110print01.csv wa-61print01.csv > MasterPrinterList.csv 2>nul
```

the file names are printed in error stream so all you need is to add `2>nul` at the end.

type also accepts wildcards so you can make your line shorter e.g

```
type lak*.csv or*.csv tac*.csv wa*.csv  > MasterPrinterList.csv 2>nul
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on the wild cards. I don't think i'm going to use it, but I'll keep it in mind.